# Loading the same javascript file on multiple locations

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/show_ad.js"></script>
```

I put the line from above on multiple locations on the page. This script will put a iframe element on the page. The problem is that the script only loads once when I use this script multiple times. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks already.

Comment: You'd have to talk to whomever wrote the script to see how they intended it to behave in this situation.

Comment: I wrote the script myself..

Comment: there could be 100 reasons why something "only works once"; post the actual code for an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across this article today, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

It goes over how to sandbox 3rd party JavaScript files in iframes so that they don't conflict with each other & can't do anything malicious.

After viewing your comment that you wrote the script yourself, you may want to try wrapping your entire script in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). For example:

```
(function() {
 // script here
})();
```

It will ensure that globals you may have defined don't conflict / only exist within that closure.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `script` tags to the page every time you want to put an `iframe` on the page, why don't you just put the `iframe` there instead?

If you really want to use the method you're currently using, wrap `show_ads.js` code in some sort function (like `var show_ads = function () {...}`), and have additional javascript on the page to call this function when you need it, and capture the `iframe`. Then insert that `iframe` into the page at the spot that you want, instead of putting a `script` tag there.

Comment: The reason why I use the script tags is because the website owner can't give me modification rights. So if I just give him the iframe tags then its not possible for me to change the size or source.